# What could the notation $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$ mean, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of measurable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, notation

In the book *Weak convergence and Empirical Processes*, by Aad W. van der Vaart and Jon A. Wellner, on page 81, the notation $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$ appears, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of measurable functions, $f \in \mathcal{F}$ then $f \colon \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I am not sure what $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$ is. I know what $l^\infty$ is by itself, the set of bounded sequences (Wikipedia), but not sure about this one.

Comment: Will you please give a precise reference to where this is used?

Comment: "Weak convergence and Empirical Processes", Aad W. van der Vaart Jon A. Wellner, page 81 (2.1). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Here's a link to Google Books for those interested: http://books.google.com/books?id=seH8dMrEgggC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22Weak%20convergence%20and%20Empirical%20Processes%22&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is mentioned as an "indexing set" suggests to me that it actually means just that: the everywhere bounded functions from $\mathcal{F}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check page 34 (which I got by checking the List of Symbols on page 506)?

http://books.google.com/books?id=seH8dMrEgggC&pg=PA34

[image]